# How to prevent exposing WCF class to client

Tags: wcf, object

I just want to know is there any way to prevent exposing `WCF class` directly to client who consuming service.
Because by default client can make the service proxy object through service Interface or by `Class object`. So can we do any operation in `WCF` that client cannot see the `Class` at there end only they can call the service method through Interface or service channel.

Thanks

Comment: Make your Service REST.

Comment: Thanks Faizan,but in simple WCF service is there any way...

Comment: I don't understand your question.  The client can't see the service interface or class (unless it's in a shared assembly that the client has direct access to).  All the client sees is the available methods with their return types and parameters - the actual implementation of those methods is not known to the client.  This isn't a WCF thing - it's a SOAP thing.

Comment: Thanks Tim,But my question was if i am going to consume any service at that time during creation of WCF object client can see the WCF interface name/Class name and servicechannel ..So if you are creating a class object you can see all methods that of the class right ,now is there any way that i dont want to make a class object(means can't see the class object) and call the service method through Interface...